# How to disable LIBSVM's Cross Validation?

Tags: matlab, libsvm

Is this possible, if so, how? I tried setting -v 1 but it says that v >= 2. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try it without `-v`?

Comment: Yes, but in the instructions it says the default goes to 5 so I assumed it used 5 fold validation in this case.